# Bootstrap: ordering columns push and pull

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a 2-columnpage; On mobile I want the right-column to be on top. 
This is the code so far:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">    
<div class="col-xs-0 col-xs-pull-0 col-sm-6 col-md-9">Left column</div>     
<div class="col-xs-0 col-xs-push-0 col-sm-6 col-md-3">Right column</div>
```

The right columns on mobile is still placed under the left column. I've tried all kind of variations.
If I replace col-xs-0 to col-xs-12, the grid runs out of the viewport (horizontal scrollbar)
What do I do wrong?

Comment: Try doing mobile-first and change the markup so that the right column comes first. *Then* do the push and pull for the larger viewports.